# Add Product to Customer Cart

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I want to configurable product add to cart programmatically in magento 2 to customer cart

Answer (score 0):

You can use following approach for the solution :

First we need to load a customer for ex :

```
$customer->loadByEmail($orderData['email']);
```

then we need to create an empty cart and quote as follows :

```
$cartId = $this->cartManagementInterface->createEmptyCart(); //Create empty cart
$quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($cartId); // load empty cart quote
$quote->setStore($store);
$customer= $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
$quote->setCurrency();
$quote->assignCustomer($customer);
```

after above you need to add products to the quote

```
$options = array(
                90 => 53,
                143 => 170
            );    
$params = array(
    'product' => $productId,
    'super_attribute' => $options,
    'qty' => $qty
);    
$_product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);    
$quote->addProduct($_product,$params);    
$quote->save();
```

Where productRepository is an instance of \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface

Comment: thanks for answer but i want to add product to customer cart

Comment: Please check my update answer for a better idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Find the customer in the backend, click on edit.
You should see a tab on the left called shopping cart. You would expect that it should work from there. But it doesn't. Or at least I didn't find a way to make it work.

But here is how I did.
Click on the 'Create order' from the customer edit screen.
Select a store view to associate the order with.
Then add to the order the products you want to put in the cart.
After adding them, you will see for each line a column named Action. Select from the dropdown for each product "Move to shopping cart".
Then hit "Update items and qty's".
That's it.

Comment: I think he needs to add it programmatically ?